# python3 で input に対する空行の入力を判定したいが EOFError が発生しない

Tags: python, python3

下記のコードで空行が入力されるまで標準入力を受け付けたいのですが、改行のみを入力しても処理が終了しません。
入力を終了させる方法を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
def get_input():
    while True:
        try:
            yield ''.join(input())
        except EOFError:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = list(get_input()) # [a1, a2, a3, ...]
```

環境：
MacOSX10.12.6
python3.5.1

Comment: Python 3 なのであれば、`raw_input` ではなく `input` なのではないでしょうか？ ([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954834/5989200))

Comment: 「aaa<改行>bbb<改行>ccc<改行>」と入力したときに、a1 = "aaa", a2 = "bbb", a3 = "ccc" のようになってほしい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: すみません。raw_input()ではなくinput()です。また、改行は空行です。　質問してくださった方ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

改行するだけでは EOF は発生しません。空行を認識させたいのであれば、EOFError ではなく別の方法を使う必要があります。

「空行まで1行ずつ読み込みたい」という意図では、たとえば以下のコードが参考になると思います。

```
def get_input():
    while True:
      try:
        line = input()  # Python 2.x と Python 3.x で input() の挙動が異なるので注意
        if line == '':  # 空行の場合、line の中身は空文字列
          break
        else:
          yield line
      except EOFError:
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = list(get_input())
    print(a)
```

---

補足： EOFError についてですが、macOS のターミナルの場合、<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> を押すことで EOF を伝えることができます([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21364313/5989200))。

たとえば次のように入力すると、EOFError が発生し、質問文にある元々のプログラムは終了します。

```
aaa
bbbbbbb
cc
# ここで Control+D を押し、必要なら改行する
```

また、end of file というくらいなので、ファイルから入力することも可能です。

```
$ cat input.txt
aaa
bbbbbbb
cc
$ python example.py < input.txt
```

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。助かりました！