# EOFErrorについての質門です。

Tags: python, python3, bash, macos

imacで、python3を勉強中です。書籍に掲載されている簡単な条件分岐のプログラムを実行したのですが、問題なく実行される場合と、下記エラーが表示される時があります。何故でしょうか。
EOFErrorが表示された場合、一度bashを終了して、再度立ち上げるとうまくいきます。

ファイル名 180130_bunki01.py

```
user = input('気温は何度ですか? ')

kion = int(user)

if 25 <= kion :
    print('気温は{0}度なので、\n熱いお茶を出して下さい。'.format(kion))
else:
    print('気温は{0}なので、\n冷たいお茶を出して下さい。'.format(kion))
```

エラーメッセージ

```
気温は何度ですか? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "180130_bunki01.py", line 1, in <module>
    user = input('気温は何度ですか? ')
EOFError
```

実行は、python3のパスをpyという名前でエイリアス登録し、

```
py 180130_bunki01.py
```

としています。因みに、他にも簡単な条件分岐のプログラムを作成したのですが、すべて、inputの部分で引っかかっているようです。

Comment: 関連情報ですが、`input` による入力待ち中に Control+D と押すと EOF になるそうです。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/37352/26808

Comment: python3のパスをpyという名前でエイリアス登録してまして、py 180130_bunki01.py　で実行しています。因みに、他にも簡単な条件分岐のプログラムを作成したのですが、すべて、inputの部分で引っかかってようです。一度、bashを終了せずに、閉じて新しいbashを立ち上げて、py 180130_bunki01.py　を実行すると、すべて問題なく動きます。

Comment: 「inputの部分で引っかかる」というのは、`input` によるプロンプトが出て、それに文字列を入力してEnterを押したあとにエラーが出る、ということですか？ エイリアスの設定があるということは、`~/.profile` や `~/.bashrc` などを作成していると思いますが、これらを空にしても同じ問題が起きますか？

Comment: エラーのタイミングですが、py 180130_bunki01.py　Enterで出ます。文字列を入力する前に起きます。今、取り敢えず新規でbashを立ち上げてしまったので、症状ななくなり、通常通りエラーなく実行されます。今度またエラーが出た時のために、一度~/.profile や ~/.bashrc を空に様子を見てみます。